# Android db connection and try catch regarding scope

Tags: java, android, database, connection, try-catch

Hi I'm trying to clean up my code to remove errors stating that my db connection was opened but not closed correctly.

If I have a db.open() then a few try catch statements around db query's then a db.close() following the try catch will it use the same db connection within the try catches or does java discretely run the try catch statements so the db connection is not available.

In short, should i have code something like this:

```
db.open();
try {
 // here
 db.getThings()
} catch () {
 // there
}
try {
 // here 2
 db.getMoreThings()
} catch () {
 // there 2
}
db.close();
```

Or this:

```
try {
 // here
 db.open();
 db.getThings()
 db.close();
} catch () {
 // there
}

try {
 // here 2
 db.open();
 db.getMoreThings()
 db.close();
} catch () {
 // there 2
}
```

I'd have thought the first solution of opening one db connection is the better one. But i'm running into issues with not closing db connections and i'm at the point of thinking there's a fundamental issue with my design.

I've also tried opening the connection in onResume() then close in onPause() but still having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a recommendation to close DB connection as soon as you selected data, so in my app I mainly use the following template:

```
db.open();
try {
    // select data
} finally {
    db.close();
}
```

it worked for me.

Comment: Hmm I was just considering putting the `db.close()` in the `Finally` statement. I realised for starters, that if my `try / catch` actually catches an exception then my `db.close()` will not run, but using finally it will guarantee a `db.close()`. I have a question though: Do you think its better having the db.open() before the try statement or INSIDE the try? Thank you for you advice

Comment: I put db.open before try as it possibly can raise some exception. And if you put it inside try -- finally and db.open fires an exception then db.close in the finally block will also fire an exception (something like "DB not open") which will mask the original one.

Comment: Thank you. Just implementing this now, see how it goes

Comment: working perfectly, cheers. I put `db.open()` before try and `db.close()` in `finally()`. No more "unclosed db" errors now on any screens.